# SICStus Prolog 4.3.2: clpfd got no power?

Tags: prolog, portability, clpfd, sicstus-prolog

Some of my Prolog programs could profit *quite* a bit if I could replace **all** `(is)/2`-based integer arithmetics by their [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) counterpart.

So I want the power ... with [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) ... so I can replace `X is 10^3` with something clpfd-y :)

Consider the following five Prolog processors supporting [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd):

- [GNU Prolog](http://www.gprolog.org/) 1.4.4

  ```
  ?- X #= 10^3.
  uncaught exception: error(type_error(fd_evaluable,(^)/2),(#=)/2)

  ?- X #= 10**3.
  X = 1000.
  ```
- [SWI-Prolog](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) 7.3.14

  ```
  ?- use_module(library(clpfd)).  % autoload would be even more awesome
  true.

  ?- X #= 10^3.
  X = 1000.

  ?- X #= 10**3.
  ERROR: Domain error: `clpfd_expression' expected, found `10**3'
  ```
- [B-Prolog](http://www.picat-lang.org/bprolog/index.html) 8.1

  ```
  ?- X #= 10^3.
  X #= 10^3.
  *** error(illegal_array_access,10^3)

  ?- X #= 10**3.
  X = 1000.
  ```
- [SICStus Prolog](https://sicstus.sics.se/) 4.3.2

  ```
  ?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
  true.

  ?- X #= 10^3.
  ! Existence error in (^)/2
  ! constraint user:wi(^)/2 does not exist
  ! goal:  10^3

  ?- X #= 10**3.
  ! Existence error in user:(**)/2
  ! constraint user:(**)/2 does not exist
  ! goal:  10**3
  ```

Ideas / hints / advice, please. 
What can I do? Use some [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) compatibility layer(s), perhaps?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Far more difficult will be to handle numeric range differences ! See for instance Markus Triska [thesis](http://www.metalevel.at/drt.pdf)

Comment: @CapelliC. I didn't get that... What exactly are you referring to? Please point me to some page in mat's thesis... Or are you possibly referring to one of the following limitations? How multiple solvers can interact gracefully? Or how built-ins like `length/2` can't handle FD vars because the implementation hasn't caught up yet?

Comment: @CapelliC. Merry X-mas, btw! Rise and shine for the lord has come to the Earth...

Comment: start on page 21 (par. 3.3.1), then read on :)

Comment: @CapelliC: Aye! Aye! Thank you!

Comment: @CapelliC. So you are worried about some of the idiosyncrasies that [tag:gnu-prolog] has.... right?

Comment: not really... but I like Prolog for its own merits, and despite its problems... I appreciate the efforts to make it more useful, and hope Markus will succeed fully with his high level objectives. From an engineering viewpoint (that's the perspective from where I read your question), consider that the author of B-Prolog created a *new* language (Picat) to be free and unencumbered from Prolog heritage.

Comment: @CapelliC. Fair enough. OTOH Neng-Fa Zhou stated in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/picat-lang/A-ooHX8k9mA (02/2015): "B-Prolog's development is not stopped, but the main focus has shifted to Picat. *Picat share the same engine with B-Prolog.* You can load and run B-Prolog's byte code with Picat as follows: [...]" No bridges are burned:-)

Comment: Note the difference between: `X in -1..1, Y #=(X*X)*(X*X).` and `X in -1..1, Y#=X*X*X*X.`

Comment: @false. With SICStus clpfd? mat's clpfd: `?- Xin -1..1, Y #=(X*X)*(X*X).` Answer: `X in -1..1, X^4#=Y, Y in 0..1.` and `?- X in -1..1, Y #=X*X*X*X.` has answer: `X in -1..1, X^4#=Y, Y in 0..1` (same)

Comment: @repeat: SICStus. See your own tags

Comment: In general, `X^Y` should propagate more easily and more thoroughly than `X*X*...*X`. So pow would be a win for sicstus clpfd...

Comment: Try `X^X#=X.` anywhere

Comment: Did you considered Logtalk ? Imo it's **absolutely** the best for portability. A portability layer is also available in Swipl and several others (well, at least I believe...)

Comment: @false. I tried `X^X #= X` in SWI. I got the answer `X^X #= X`, so it did not propagate a bit. Sure, I would have liked different answers (like `X in {-1}\/{1}` or `X in -1..1, X*X #= 1` or `X in -1..1, X^X #= X` better), but that's a different issue... For in SWI `X #= 1^1` runs. In SICStus I have to write `X is 1^1`...

Answer (score 2):

**Quick hack to the rescue?**

Warning: massive overkill ahead, but... does it even work? And is it portable?

Let's check it out!

- SWI-Prolog 7.3.14

  - using [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq)

    ```
    ?- use_module(library(clpq)).
    true.

    ?- clpq:{X = 10^3}, integer(X).
    X = 1000.                          % <== SUCCESS!
    ```
  - using [clpr](/questions/tagged/clpr)

    ```
    ?- use_module(library(clpr)).
    true.

    ?- clpr:{X = 10^3}, integer(X).
    false.
    ```
- SICStus Prolog 4.3.2

  - using [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq)

    ```
    ?- use_module(library(clpq)).
    true.

    ?- clpq:{X = 10^3}, integer(X).
    false.
    ```
  - using [clpr](/questions/tagged/clpr)

    ```
    ?- use_module(library(clpr)).
    true.

    ?- clpr:{X = 10^3}, integer(X).
    false.
    ```

**1X** success, **3X** failure... Works, well, kind of... Then again, I guess it ain't it.

Comment: `clpr` and `clpq` do work as expected:  a float `1000.0` for `10^3` ; and a `rat(1000,1)` for `clpq`.

Comment: I fear clpfd is not compatible - out of the box, at least - with clpq/clpr. So your solution seems very hacky to me.... sorry. Maybe 'simple' term rewriting, with goal_expansion, could help, and eventually syntax macros based on :- if(swi) or :-if(sictus)...

Comment: @false. It's a matter of expectations. So (while that breaks my hack), should  clpq in SWI rather give `rat(1000,1)` instead of `1000`, too?

Comment: @CapelliC. Which problems did you encounter mixing two solvers? Would you see combining solvers as promising/interesting? Apart from mixed-integer linear programming? So far, I have found the following about solver interoperability via attributed variables: https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/CLPFD-Coexisting.html#CLPFD-Coexisting , https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/lib_002datts.html .

Comment: I don't know enough to answer your question... sorry but I'm - kind of -  self learner, so maybe it's just my intuition...

Comment: @CapelliC. Okay, no problem! None at all! But I won't let you off my hook regarding that "modelling and solving constraint problems *cooperatively* in different clp(X) " question :-)

Comment: @repeat: You are now throwing everything into a single question. Your question was about power. clpq and clpr have since the early 1990s always had `^` as an exponentiation operator. But they are not directly compatible with the integers. Never had, and as for clpr never should be.

Comment: @false. Thx 4 pointing out that the question should not have the tag [tag:clpq]!

Answer (score 0):

You can use for constant expressions:

```
?- X is 10^3.
X = 1000.
```

Which should work in a ISO compliant prolog thanks to [corr2](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#pow).

It will also propagate inside CLP(FD) as if it were X #= 10^3:

```
?- Y #= X+1, X is 10^3.
Y = 1001
X = 1000
```